# How to remove the uninstall msi using MSBUILD

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, msbuild-4.0

Can anyone help me to get the custom script (i.e. using Target) sample to uninstall the msi instance which is already installed on a server using MSBUILD.

A sample code example will be more helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below mentioned MSBUILD script helped me to uninstall the msi:

```
<Target Name="UnInstallMSI">
    <Message  Text="UnInstallation of MSI Started..." Importance="high"></Message>
    <Exec Command='msiexec.exe /x &quot;$(MSILocation)&quot; /qn /l*vx &quot;$(LogFile)&quot;' ContinueOnError="false" />
    <Message  Text="UnInstallation of MSI Completed Successfully..." Importance="high"></Message>
  </Target>
```

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro